# how to animate filtered image with css

Tags: css

```
img:hover{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

This would transform the image from color to grayscale. But I wanted to it with animation effect. I can do this with jQuery. But I need css-only solution.

So, how can I give animation effect while hovering to the image?

---

**Update**

I've tried this but not working in firefox brwoser and even in IE11 it's not grayscaling!

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */



    filter: grayscale(100%);

    transition : filter 500ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-filter 500ms linear;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45CCS/1/)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp - This is all about CSS3 animations, im guessing you would probably just bind them inside the hover

Comment: @AndyHolmes http://w3fools.com/

Comment: http://demosthenes.info/blog/540/Animating-CSS3-Image-Filters - this might be more what you're after then?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a `transition`

**Example**

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);

    transition : filter 500ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-filter 500ms linear;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think it is possible to get a transition to work using an svg for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 1s
}
```

see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/45CCS/

Comment: Much better with a semicolon at the end ;-)